# Print specified length of strings after decimal point Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, numpy, output, slice

I am using python **odeint** function to solve 5 system of Ordinary Differential Equation i-e **dT, dU, dV, dW, dI** mentioned in the code below. I am printing the values of the mentioned 5 ode's. The code and output is mentioned below.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

initial_condi = [.1,.1,.1,.1,.1]# Initial Conditions
t = np.arange(0, 18,.1)    

def equation(w, t): #System of ODEs defined in Equation 1
    T, U, V,W,I = w
    dT = -0.010*T + 8.916*U + 0.007
    dU = U *W* 0.435 - U * 1.745 + 0.7002 * U        
    dV = -V * 0.010 + U* 0.41 +W * 0.012 - 2.390 * V        
    dW= V * 0.0074 + 0.306 -W * 0.0945 -W * U * 1471.7        
    dI= -223.54 * I - 0.190 * U + 0.0120 + 228 * U

    return  dT, dU, dV, dW, dI    
result_init = odeint(equation, initial_condi, t)
for x in result:
    print(str(x))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0.18524374 0.09011406 0.08212658 0.00229254 0.09231991]
[0.26201417 0.08118263 0.06771829 0.00254143 0.08317513]
[0.33115033 0.07313725 0.05607613 0.00281733 0.07493757]
 .
 .
  more values
 .
[9.22757317e-01 1.04581662e-06 1.06821916e-02 2.17837399e+00 5.47479101e-05]
```

I want the value of **x** should be of length 6 after the decimal point for all strings i.e **dT, dU, dV, dW, dI**. The output values keep increasing after few iterations. I tried slicing with **print(str(x[:2]))** but it removes the whole last three strings and returns only first two strings i.e **dT, dU**. I also tried below mentioned *print* methods but it shows the correct first few outputs but it start rounding off the values to zero after the half iteration as mentioned below. For comparison I am showing the actual and formatted output together **dT i.e, x[1]**.

```
print({:.6s}'.format('{:0.6f}'.format(x[1])))
print('%.6s' % ('%.6f' % x[1])))
print("{:10.6f}".format(x[1]))
print(f'{x[1]:9.6f}')
print('%1.6f' % x[1])
print('{0: >#016.4f}'. format(float(x[1])))
```

First five output comparison

```
0.09011406483415754 --   0.090114
0.08118263136404366 --   0.081183
0.0731372488594067 --   0.073137
0.06589001317279601 --   0.065890
0.059361743384116844 --   0.059362
```

Last Five Output Comparison

```
1.0909958951511154e-06 --   0.000001
1.0788241960599524e-06 --   0.000001
1.0672502539780622e-06 --   0.000001
1.0562545312422881e-06 --   0.000001
1.0458166159301957e-06 --   0.000001
```

My desired output is mentioned below. Thanks

```
[0.185243 0.090114 0.082126 0.002292 0.092319]
[0.262014 0.081182 0.067718 0.002541 0.083175]
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but it's probably better than what you want. This is a typical case where you want to use [General format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#index-2).

Modify your code as follow:

```
for xx in result_init:
    print(['{0:.6g}'.format(x) for x in xx])
```

which gives you for example:

```
...
['0.923201', '1.06725e-06', '0.0105805', '2.15882', '5.47698e-05']
['0.922979', '1.05625e-06', '0.0106316', '2.16864', '5.47586e-05']
['0.922757', '1.04582e-06', '0.0106822', '2.17837', '5.47479e-05']
```

If instead of string representation you want to print float then simply reconvert back to float. Keep in mind that you are loosing precision because those missing digits are lost.

```
for xx in result_init:
    print([float('{0:.6g}'.format(x)) for x in xx])
```

Comment: It does works but I also wants to avoid the scientific notation "e-05". I don't want it. I only need six regular numbers after the decimal point...

Comment: If you don't want the exponential notation simply replace the 'g' with 'f' in my code ('{0:.6f}'), but wasn't that your problem? I mean for example 1.2e-06 is 0.0000012 but of course with only 6 digits after the comma it becomes 0.000001